# Appium - Questions regarding the iOS simulator

Tags: ios, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios

I want to test the example `TestApp` for iOS in the iOS simulator using JUnit.

Therefore I have written a simple test that access an UI element.

Each time I run this test, the Appium test server automatically starts a new simulator running the `TestApp`.
Is there a possibility to avoid these automatic actions and perform them manually (regardless of this is an useful practice or not)?

For example I want to do these actions manually:

- start the simulated iPhone by command
- load/install the TestApp on the
  simulated iPhone
- start the `TestApp` on the simulated iPhone by tap command
- perform swipe on home screen of simulated iPhone

  1. Are these actions even possible through Appium at all?
  2. If yes - how?

Thank you.

Comment: why do you want to perform these actions manually? what different would you do as compared to the same steps being performed by automation?

Comment: This is really awkward idea... no idea why you want to do this. Just run iOS Simulator and do everything manually if you want to do it manually...

Comment: :). That was not my question... I simply want to know if this is possible. And if yes how. I want to understand how I could do these actions.